# Screen flickering and lines, but works with monitor

Tags: display, gpu, microsoft-surface, microsoft

Microsoft surface 3 screen is not visible, lines are appearing and flickering. It works with monitors and the touchscreen is tracking perfectly in diagnostics.

I’m assuming a piece of hardware needs replaced but I don’t know what.

Any ideas on how to resolve?

[screen photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5r3E.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Could be the backlight, a bad /intermittent cable, or the display.  It is not evident in this case which part is bad but the cable seems a likely possibility.

Probably best to get it serviced as a shop can determine which part and then will only charge for the bad part plus the labor to replace.

A Surface laptop is not trivial to disassemble (many new small laptop are tricky to take apart).   So if you do not have small laptop disassembly skills and experience, you are very much advised to use an experienced shop.